# Android studio emulator sqlite db file

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

So I want to view my db structure through some db browser application, but for that I need to get `mydatabase.db` file from application installed on emulator. I found this file through Device File explorer under `data/data/package.com/mydatabase.db` but when I open this file in some sqlite editor it shows that its empty no tables etc.. I'm using **Room** database so I'm thinking maybe room does something to this file that I can't open it because under database folder there is three files `mydatabase.db`, `mydatabase.db-shm`, `mydatabase.db-wal` which I never seen before when I was using just `sqlite` and maybe there is other ways to check structure of my db?

Comment: The `-wal` file is for write-ahead logging, which Room 1.1.0 enables. Try copying all three files, then opening the `.db` file. WAL is a standard SQLite feature and has been around for years, so most up-to-date SQLite clients should be able to handle it.

Comment: Write as an answer I will accept it, thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-wal` file is for write-ahead logging (WAL), which Room 1.1.0 enables. Try copying all three files, then opening the `.db` file.

WAL is a standard SQLite feature and has been around for years, so most up-to-date SQLite clients should be able to handle it.